# Why do Apache config files `httpd.conf.work.[hash]` exist and how are they used?

Tags: apache, centos, whm

In the same folder as the active Apache `httpd.conf` file are a set of `httpd.conf.work.[hash]` files. Where [hash] is an 8 character hash consisting of a-z A-Z 0-9 and _

The data they contain is essentially an `httpd.conf' file which suggests one is generated each time the main config file is updated and working.

I can see from a search that in some cases it stops a WHM CentOS install from updating after using the include config options.

Are they Cent OS specific? Can they be deleted? Why do the cause the include error above when they aren't referenced in `httpd.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, every time you do change the apache configuration, cPanel/WHM scripts automatically store the previous configuration as **httpd.conf.bak**. This happens when you modify your apache configuration from WHM (and not by manually editing the httpd.conf file).

I can't provide you a proper answer about the hash files but as a suggestion you could ask that on cPanel forums. I am pretty sure that you will receive the desired answer from any of the cPanel/WHM staff guys.